# r-tree how to calculate minimum bounding rectangles of non leaf nodes

Tags: bounding-box, r-tree

I have many building footprints and want to store them in a r-tree structure.I want to understand that in a r-tree structure leaf nodes are minimum bounding rectangles (MBR) of real objects, in my case building footprints. But I could not understand how MBRs of non leaf nodes can be calculated and I want to know how can it be done (In the picture Green boxes). I suppose there are many possible solution but I just want to know only one of them. 
[image: Rtree example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bounding boxes of inner nodes are computed **exactly the same way as for leaf nodes**.

You need the minimum and maximum in each axis.

Comment: I respect your answer. If you can you explain more detailed it would be very helpful. Can you explain for example why green bounding box (N) does not include C

Comment: Because C is not in N, obviously. C is in P. You only compute the bounding box for your node contents, just as with the leaves.

Comment: There isn't anything to add but "minimum and maximum in each axis" is how to compute the MBR.

Comment: Ok that is obvious but Why C is child of P and not N.  Is there a possibility  maybe for example different green MBRs which N include A, B, C and P include only D and E why it is not like this.

Comment: Yes, if you split differently, you get a different tree, but that is not related to MBR computation.

Answer (score 1):

The MBR of a non-leaf node is the **union** of its children nodes (can be leaf or non-leaf nodes) so that it is the **bounding box** of offspring data.

Take the two-dimensional example in your picture, suppose the children nodes `A(X_amin, X_amax, Y_amin, Y_amax)` and `B(X_bmin, X_bmax, Y_bmin, Y_bmax)`, the non-leaf parent node is `N(min(X_amin, X_bmin), max(X_amax, X_bmax), min(Y_amin, Y_bmin), max(Y_amax, Y_bmax))`.

Comment: I get that but I don't understand how these green MBRs are organized. For example why N does not include  C

Comment: @blackSwan So instead of a problem about the way to calculate MBR, you are asking about the **chooseNode** and **nodeSplit** strategy during the process of rtree construction. For example, the original Guttman way is choose the child node with the least enlargement to include the insertion data. There are other more complicated or efficient ways. Refer to the [paper](http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/SI-LS/papers/Gut84.pdf) or this [java implementation](https://github.com/davidmoten/rtree) for details.

Comment: Thank you @Ambling . That's the confirmation I am looking for.